# Recommendations for a short, yet theoretically rigorous, seminar or course on principal components analysis

Tags: self-study, pca

I am looking for a short course (1 week or less) that teaches the theoretical and applied aspects of principal components analysis in a mathematically rigorous way. I've seen university courses on multivariate statistics in general or the linear model, but not just PCA. Travel is not an issue, so good international courses are welcome, as long as they are in English. Also, I do not want to just learn how to run a PCA using some software package and interpret the results; I want to learn the detailed underlying theory as well.

I cannot attend a semester-long course, nor do I want to do a web-only class.

Comment: Have you tried looking at departmental websites for clinical psychology programs to see if they offer any summer short courses on psychometrics / scale development / factor analysis?

Comment: @AdamO I have looked at some of these, but it seems that social and biological science versions of PCA do not go into depth on the math, just how to run and interpret the results.

Comment: Would you be interested in literature with information on PCA, mostly theory and some practice?

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh yes, that would be good as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend the book **"The Elements of Statistical Learning: Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction"** (2nd ed.) by *Trevor Hastie*, *Robert Tibshirani* and *Jerome Friedman*. Along with the printed edition, this IMHO beautiful (both content-wise and visually) book is available as free download in PDF format at the link on this page: http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn.

**Section 14.5** of the book is focused on `PCA` and is, in my humble opinion, theoretically relatively rigorous. The subsequent sections (14.6 and later) are focused on presenting some **alternatives** to `PCA`. Also, section 3.5.1 is focused on the related topic of *principal components regression*. Hope this helps (and I helped you to save some pocket change for a trip to a seminar/course :-).

Comment: Superb...and FREE. What more could one want!

Comment: @Eupraxis1981: Glad I could help!